# Passing variables from c# web browser to IE

Tags: c#

I have a web browser in a c# application.  Some of the web pages viewed through the web browser have a form that submit to a new window which opens IE through the window.open javascript function.  The problem I'm having is that the session created in the web browser doesn't transfer to IE when the new window is opened.  I want to know if there is a way to keep the session in the new IE window or if there is a way to add the session variables to the new window when it opens?

Comment: If you ran the same pages directly in a browser, would they maintain session id?

Comment: Yes. If I had IE open, the session is maintained in a cookie so it's available to any IE browser window.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass information to IE in the URL in the querystring; a little coordination on the server side will allow you to use that to have the IE window have linked session information to the C# app that opened the IE window.

Comment: We can't change any of the actual pages we will be browsing.

Comment: I doubt that it can be done, then; I believe what you're running up against is a specific security issue.